# How to add records to databse via sql in Java

Tags: java, sql, insert, sql-update, sql-delete

I am working a Airsoft application.

I'm trying to add records to a MS Access Database via SQL in Java. I have established a link to the database, with the following:

```
   try
   {
        //String Driver = "sun.java.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";

        Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");

        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://" + URL,"","");

        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

        System.out.println("Connection Established!");

        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM AirsoftGunRentals");
        tblRent.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));


   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error");
   }
```

I am using Ucanaccess to access my MS database. It is reading the database and is displaying to a JTable. However, I need to create three JButtons to add, delete and update the table. I have tried to code the add button, and I have tried to add a record, but it crashes and gives me errors.

```
   try
   {
        //String Driver = "sun.java.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
        Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://" + URL,"","");

        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

        System.out.println("Connection Established!");

        String Query= "INSERT INTO AirsoftGunRentals(NameOfGun, Brand, TypeOfGuns, NumberOfMagazines,Extras,NumberAvailable,UnitRent)"+
             "VALUES('"+pName+"','"+pBrand+"','"+pTypeOfGun+"','"+pNumMags+"','"+pExtras+"','"+pNumberAvail+"','"+pRent+"');";

        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(Query);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Success!");


   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error");
   }
```

I have attempted all three, hoping for a result. But am still getting big errors. The only difference between the buttons is that one adds, one deletes and one updates the table. Other then that, the code is the same, minus variables.

Comment: Which errors? Post the complete exception stack trace. And use prepared statements. (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find an answer on how to add, delete and update records to a MS Access DB. This is what I found, after I declared the connection, and the prepped statement. I will try to explain to the best I can. I had to add values individually using this:

(pstmt = Prepped Statement Variable)

pstmt.setWhatever(1,Variable);

And it works fine now. I use the same method to delete and update records.

This is the basic query format:

String SQLInsert = "INSERT INTO Tbl VALUES(NULL,?,?,?,?)";

The NULL in the statement is the autonumber in the table. and .setWhatever() clause replaces the question marks with the data types. Thus manipulating the database.

Thank you everyone for all your contributions. It helped a lot, and made this section a lot more understandable.

Answer (score 1):

As Brahim mentionned it, you should use `stmt.executeUpdate(Query)` whenever you update / insert or delete data. Also with this particular query, given your String concatenation (see end of line), there is no space between the ")" and the "VALUES" which probably causes a malformed query.

However, I can see from your code that you are not very experienced with such use-cases, and I'd like to add some pointers before all hell breaks loose in your project :

- Use `PreparedStatement` instead of `Statement` and replace variables by placeholders to prevent SQL Injection. 
  The code that you are using here is extremely prone to SQL injection - if any user has any control over any of the variables, this could lead to a full database dump (theft), destruction of data (vandalism), or even in machine takeover if other conditions are met. 
  A good advice is to never use the `Statement` class, better be safe than sorry :)
- Respect Java Conventions (or be coherent). 
  In your example you define the `String Query`, while all the other variables start with lower-case (as in Java Conventions), instead of `String query`. Overtime, such little mistakes (that won't break a build) will lead to bugs due to mistaking variables with classnames etc :)

Good luck on your road to mastering this wonderful language ! :)

Comment: This is actually for a school project, and we only have to use it once. EVER! Quick one, if you use the executeUpdate() clause, will you need a result set for it to dump? Or is it a standalone line? Thank you for the help. It gives a more open view on the task now.

Comment: Regarding return value of the executeUpdate() clause, as the Javadoc states, an integer is returned :
 
'either (1) the row count for SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statements or (2) 0 for SQL statements that return nothing'

So if you use an executeUpdate() to update 42 rows, it will return 42

Comment: Regarding the SQL injection, I recommend you to take the habit to code securely to prepare a carreer of quality and secure code :)

Besides that, some of your classmates probably did the same mistake - it could be fun to demonstrate the injection (in a benevolent / benign fashion ofcourse) in class :)

Security is a big matter and will be even more with the overwhelmingly presence of code running everywhere in our everyday life, it is a good example to raise awareness among your classmates. I'll let you consider that :)

Comment: I am not too worried about SQL Injection. What I am worried about is getting the base SQL to work, then I can worry about all of that.

Answer (score 0):

First add a space before the quotation marks like this :

```
      String Query= "INSERT INTO AirsoftGunRentals(NameOfGun, Brand, TypeOfGuns, NumberOfMagazines,Extras,NumberAvailable,UnitRent) "+
         " VALUES('"+pName+"','"+pBrand+"','"+pTypeOfGun+"','"+pNumMags+"','"+pExtras+"','"+pNumberAvail+"','"+pRent+"');";
```

And use `stmt.executeUpdate(Query);` instead of : `stmt.executeQuery(Query);`in your insert, update and delete queries. For select queries you can keep it.

Comment: Ah. I see now. So the spaces in between the the statement will read it as a plain SQL statement? Ironically, I got this code from stack as well.